# What is a metaphorical equivalent for "incidental positive results" or "unexpected positive outcomes"

Tags: metaphors

I read what was offered as an antonym for "camel's nose" and found "toehold" as the best fit but I'm hoping to get even better ideas. However, if the camel's nose could be used for positive outcomes, it would work for me. Please try not to suggest words from economic jargon. The text I'm translating is actually a literary one.

Context: You take a trip to enjoy yourself but you happen to find your ultimate goal there: you get something that originally was not supposed to be gained, you could have hoped for it though..

PS: English is not my language of fluency and I appreciate you bearing with the possible mistakes I make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**serendipity**: finding things by fortunate accident.
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/serendipity

> My success in my garden is due mostly to **serendipity**.

This is not, however, a metaphor.

Comment: Could it be used in plural form? say serendipities in/of the south?

Comment: I do not see why not - 'serendipities of the south' has a nice ring to it!

Comment: which part makes the ring harsh? the plurality of serendipity or in the south?

Comment: that's a title and it's not possible to get rid of "in the south"|. But if you think the collocation of the two just doesn't work, I have to forget about serendipity.

Comment: You misunderstand me - 'serendipities of the south' sounds very poetic - that is what I meant by a nice ring (like a bell) not harsh at all.